# Generating .d.ts files for tables and handling referenced tables using dot notation in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to define the typings of a given js library I have to use.
This library is basically processing queries to a database and returning a JS object.
The parameters I can pass to the method are defined by the schema of the table, thus I want to generate the .d.ts files for each table where the columns are defined.
This works for most of the fields without problem, but some fields in the table are references to other tables.
Here I can access the field of the related table by joining the field names with a dot.

My code looks something like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-qPLouLnmwAAUlDevCyGepAFF+k+EQ0u6-xoHYACUJhUX6MGgCsIpihweLyIcWCgDw-KxHgT5iC+AF8jgqyQEgnDwJy7CwNet4EG+oByVEdbAhY6xoFoVEmOGGC4qAqH9rmQ6gOhSZYbAOGaHhJEbjQowot27Guu6KF3EeuERsI6ZtHBOQWVZBokb5nEGhFVhLDYtArLAsRiQKWSgFQkBBryAr5hpd6AdAAa0FF672oY27+XYJEAETOA1rEWEQRGNI1YSRCgDVPhk7qsTxYAAPIANJtR1pENd1UR9aADUDb1Q0smyoDjZNxEoI15ScFURCXPNDUAFKxIY5AtcN60TXI7VbTtFT7YdT4AKwrWAP7XZtnUNbtlSYEdACML0AGwACyA2DIMg4DAAcL0Q5Dl0rMI56gAA4tGPTWqAGH8uwf1VE+6UFewDFUO6V43neUyhGi2KgHdP2E5gRBdL0-SDMMijjGW0DzW9V0bbdU3bb9j2s+zfQDEMIy83MR0vcjH1rcLjOi41ehoAGrL4uRPoC+9AmIBtQA).
If I exchange `Tables.user` in line 43 with `V`, as it should be if I understnad it correctly, it will not work.

I am not sure if the problem is related to how I define the tables or I have some problem with my templates...
Also it might be related to the fact, that its defined as a method and not as a property.
I know that it is infinit deep, a restriction to 3 or max 5 would be enough for virtually all of our cases if it helps.

Comment: Can you include the exact error message too? [Here](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-video-player/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-vimeo-player/tsconfig.lib.json#L8) is an example project of a library using a native js lib. But I had to extend the `typeRoots`

Comment: Thank you for the fast response.
I do not get an error by itself.
If I keep line 43 as it is, it "works" and vs code even lists the allowed options for the field names with a depth of 1.
If I change it to `V` I can basically enter whatever I want and I will not gain an error although i should.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the problem was `Reference`.

I tried out some stuff and for whatever reason this here seems to work for me:

```
declare type Reference<T> = {
   [key in keyof T]: T[key];
} & T
```

I do not understand this, just keeping it here in case someone faces the same problem.

I managed to get a non recursive version to work
[here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEDEEsCcGcBdQHMCmA7F0CG8UBNQ8A6eWUAM0gBsUAoPFAYyq2hVDSwFsVYAHLI3YAVLACMaZAN61QoSGlzRyg9gBlICUDLlyArrEwAuUAcyzQAX1oX4ATz7sz0UAF5tFuUj2Q8JhNAKSJ6ggvCQAG4oJmIA9rE0WGghnDz+8IFowbqheHhssLDpmdm6XElYqNAmAEoo5JjoQgA8zgB8IVHQdgCSXHyx0PBJ8AByelxixhwTU9AW1rSLIKCGjLFoBKgY2LgExKQU1HQMzKzsqbwCQqCiErwecgpKKjcaWjq6WIUo8CbfhngCxscnsjlCP0Q7k+Xh8flWGSCKW40QRJRCvmKSJysQA7jtavVGmgWu1gcswNtMFgqIQSGRKDQbKcWGxQGD2HUGmwSShmsI2m5HqAANoAaxQdnkaFAErssXItwAuiZhOLJUqANxLUAAMlu2uZTFZFxR-FUoAAIjhxN92DJbA5OUSeUIAAo4AAWAGVEVl+YLoSERQBpaWyyUK24Q26hpWgFAAD1wmzIASCoAAPjNJpgs6A4gkUEkQgB+UAAAwAJFIQ5YKyFVXGE8n0HgyHV1tA8M101kADShNB2Do5cvV2v1-MTutEGtyqNqkNKqcrWCe2J6KgEKagLnE91e30lflxwViPSISCIXHUWnrfosBShOKX6WUNDX0BUeJ8RscFAuhCFVY2XFsU3bNEM2zNBZjzbNC0SZIx1ApV-yXeMkwgjsXSaPkFG5UAADVR10cs+yQUAVh6UBPSwKJ2ViZBfnZT12D4aBYkcFwOVoxp-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)
I just need to change line 50 somehow to return the correct type.
Does anyone have an idea how to accomplish this?